# Android sdk not detected in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I had the android set up in my eclipse, but when i try to open it, It asks me to set up the location in Preferences.
The location being set in Preferences gives me an error to update the ADT.
While updating the ADT plugin to the latest, installation throws an error after sometime.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: error]

Comment: what error it is throwing ?

Comment: added the error image

Comment: see @samdroid answer and try. If again any problem let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this,

1) Update eclipse.

2) go to sdk manager and update the sdk platforms tools

3) restart eclipse it will work fine..

Answer (score 3):

do following.

```
1 --> Go to Help > install new software.
2 --> click on already installed?
3 --> click on android developement tools
4 --> click on update button (shown below)
```

Answer (score 1):

SDK is working properly ... but ADT result in problem

Update your ADT to latest version that is your main problem ..the current version of your ADT is 14.0.0 but required ADT is 20.0.0 for your SDK

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to download this bundle:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Everything you need to develop Android app is included here. You do not need to do anything.
Cheers,